# Mocking class, Java

Tags: java, tomcat, junit, mocking

I'm beginner in unit testing.

I want to test MyClass. App in running on Apache Tomcat.

Classes:

```
MyClass extends Report {
    public MyClass() {
        super(); //exception in JUnit
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        GetDataFromSQL(params); // I want to test this
    }
}

Report {
    public Report(){
        //this throws null pointer exception in my JUnit tests:
        ServletContext sc = EnviromentWrapper.getServletContext(); 
    }

    //necessary method for MyClass. This method uses also other methods in this class.
    public AnyData GetDataFromSQL(params){} 
}
```

Could you quickly explain me, how to mock Report - this is complicated class, and I want to keep original code from GetDataFromSQL method.

Or may I have to do something with Tomcat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tying a non-web artifact to the web layer is a Bad Idea.**

Your report shouldn't know about the servlet context at all.

Mock `EnvironmentWrapper#getServletContext()` to return something usable and/or mock `ServletContext` to provide what you need.

Comment: I want to test MyClass, not Report (not my class)

Comment: @liquide Then mock Report using any of a zillion mocking libraries like Mockito, EasyMock, etc. You specifically stated you wanted to *keep* the "complicated code" in `GetDataFromSQL`, which is difficult to interpret without further information.

Comment: @DaveNewton - I think it's a `static` method. This complicates things a little, you can use power mock to set up the return values and then "play" them back but ordinary mocking won't help.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I guess I consider that ordinary mocking for static methods :)